# Numbering the elements of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

From a vector `q={Gamma,x,y}`, I would like to create the following corresponding list : `qn={1,2,3}`.

Other example, if I have `q={Gamma,x,y,theta}`, I would like to retrieve `qn={1,2,3,4}`.

Thank you for your help.

Is there a better way than `Table[i, {i, 1, Length[q]}]`?

Thank you

Comment: `Range[Length[q]]`

Comment: @JasonB probably you should post it as an answer.

Comment: Right! For me, it is perfect. Thank you

Comment: What would you like to get for `{Gamma, x, x, Gamma}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give what you are looking for

```
q = {Gamma, x, y, theta};
Range[Length[q]]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4} *)
```

Or, with less typing,

```
Range@Length@q
(* {1, 2, 3, 4} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Jason already commented, the usual form would be

```
Range @ Length @ q;
```

If your goal is to number the list you can do

```
> Transpose[{Range @ Length @ q, q}]
```

> {{1, Gamma}, {2, x}, {3, y}, {4, theta}}

or use `MapIndexed`

```
MapIndexed[List, q]
```

> {{Gamma, {1}}, {x, {2}}, {y, {3}}, {theta, {4}}}

Comment: Or, do `MapIndexed[Reverse@*Flatten@*List, q]` to get it in the normal form.